# Combine list - like Joins in Sql

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have two observable list of String.

I want to achieve something like this in rxjava using zip or any other operation.

If list1 has data and list2 doesn't have any data - consider the dataset of list1.

If list1 has no data and list2 has any data - consider the dataset of list2.

If list1 and list2 both have data, then take the intersection of both list.

This does not work ->

```
        String[] LEFT = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        String[] RIGHT = { "5", "6", "7", "8" };
        Observable<String> LEFT_Observable = Observable.fromArray(LEFT);
        Observable<String> RIGHT_Observable = Observable.fromArray(RIGHT);
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("HI");
        LEFT_Observable.join(RIGHT_Observable, i -> Observable.just(i), j -> Observable.just(j), (l, r) -> {
            System.out.println(l);
            System.out.println(r);
            result.add(l);
            return l + r;
        }).take(10).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the approach i took was:

- `merge` the two streams
- `filter` each value taking into consideration the null-ness/emptiness of the "left" and "right" sources
- apply `distinct` to remove duplicates

that all looks like this:

```
  @Test
  public void find_intersection_between_two_lists() {
    final List<String> leftValues  = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    final List<String> rightValues = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "4");

    final Observable<String> left  = Observable.fromIterable(leftValues);
    final Observable<String> right = Observable.fromIterable(rightValues);

    Observable.merge(left, right)
        .filter(value -> {
          if((leftValues == null || leftValues.isEmpty()) && (rightValues != null && !rightValues.isEmpty())) {
            return rightValues.contains(value);
          } else if((leftValues != null && !leftValues.isEmpty()) && (rightValues == null || rightValues.isEmpty())) {
            return leftValues.contains(value);
          } else {
            return leftValues.contains(value) && rightValues.contains(value);
          }
        })
        .distinct()
        .subscribe(
            result -> {
              System.out.println("## onNext(" + result + ")");
            },
            error -> {
              System.out.println("## onError("+ error.getMessage() + ")");
            },
            () -> {
              System.out.println("## onComplete()");
            }
        );
  }
```

the `filter` code is quite ugly. i wonder if there's a more idiomatic way to do this... but it works.

if nothing else, hopefully it at least inspires some thought!